# Issues changing default terminal in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, kde

I've installed `gnome-terminal` on my Debian PC which is running KDE on top of it. I've tried to replace default terminal emulator using "default applications" and `sudo update-alternatives –config x-terminal-emulator`, but nothing happens, I still get "konsole" as my default terminal. Does anyone have experience with solving this problem?

Comment: You don't get an dialog asking you what to use?

Comment: Nope, no dialog